# How to write click event in fabric js?

Tags: fabricjs

How to write click event for the button which present outside the canvas tag using fabric tag.

Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.

Input is save button. How to trigger click event for save button

Answer (score 0):

Working:

```
(function() {
  var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id)
  };

  var savebtnclick = $('savebtn');
  savebtnclick.onclick = function() {
    alert("test");
  }
})();
```